# Remove Dictation and Special Characters menu options from NSMenu

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I have a weird "bug". I'm creating an "Edit" menu for my Mac OSX application. It shall contain copy, paste, select all et.c. I have solved the functionality by simply connecting the appropriate selectors in the first responer to the menues.

I connect my paste menuitem to paste:
I connect my copy menuutem to copy:

This work great, and I am able to copy and paste using both the menu and shortcuts associated with them.

However, when connecting to the copy: selector of the first responer, two new menu options appear at the bottom: "Dictations" and "Special Character".

How do I remove them? I am creating the menus in Interface Builder in a xib-file.

Comment: Please don't remove those menu items. You personally may have no use for them, but other Mac users expect those menu items to be available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by manually removing the submenus from code:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];
    [self presentModalViewController:self.bookshelfController withData:nil];

    [self removeLastMenuItemsOfRedigeraMenu];
}

-(void)removeLastMenuItemsOfRedigeraMenu
{

    NSMenu *mainMenu = [NSApp mainMenu];
    for (NSMenuItem* subMenu in mainMenu.itemArray)
    {
        if ([subMenu.title isEqualToString:@"Redigera"])
        {
            NSArray *array = subMenu.submenu.itemArray;
            for (int i = (int)array.count-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (i >= 11)
                {
                    [subMenu.submenu removeItem:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please post if you have a better answer

Answer (score -1):

You can change the name of the menu item to any other, and through the awakeFromNib back with the name you want.

Something like:

```
    [_editMenuItem.submenu setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Edit",NULL)];
```

It only adds these menus when the title is "edit" on any of the supported languages​​. But just when loading the interface, then (awakeFromNib) can already put the name again.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. My title is never "edit". It is always "Redigera" (swedish for "edit"). You suggest that setting the editMenu from code removes the "Dictations" and "Special Character"?

Comment: @Sunkas Because "Redigera" is a swedish for "edit" and this behavior occurs in translations for "edit" too. Just rename for "someName" in xib and return to "Redigera" after load will works fine.

For exemple: My "edit" menu is "Editar" (Portuguese), if i call with this name will apear "Dictations" and "Special Character". So, I renamed this menu title to "someName" and on awakeFromNib I changed to "Editar" again.